# (Ruby) First x Recursive Nums

Tags: ruby, recursion, factorial

I want to write a recursive method that returns the first `num` recursive numbers.

Here is my code so far:

```
def recursive_factorials(num)
  return [1] if num == 1
  arr = recursive_factorials(num-1)
  arr << num * arr.last
end
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The expected result for `num = 6` is `[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]`, and I get `[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720]`, so I may be close but really have no idea.

Any help would be appreciated. Also, if I am not using recursion properly please let me out.

Comment: I do not get why do you expect it to end up with `120`. `6! ≡ 720`. Also, the very first `1` is for zero, that’s why you get 7 numbers out.

Comment: I do not really understand what you're saying. Very new to recursion. Could you expand a bit? Thank you

Comment: I am saying that `720` is the correct answer for `6!` and I do not understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: @mudasobwa is correct, `[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720]` is absolutely right for `6!`

Comment: The first 6 factorial numbers is [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]. Could be written as (result of the num! in parentheses): [0!(1), 1!(1), 2!(2), 3!(6), 4!(24), 5!(120)]. No?

Comment: Oh to be clear, my instructions stated that the first factorial was to be 0!, not 1!. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
def recursive_factorials(num, acc = [])
  acc << (num < 2 ? 1 : (num - 1) * recursive_factorials(num - 1, acc).last)
end
recursive_factorials 6
#⇒ [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Comment: AFAIK, tail recursion optimization is off by default in ruby.

Comment: Doesn't `recursive_factorials` have to be the very last call?

Comment: @Stefan I think that in this case it’s still a tail call, but I might be wrong.

Comment: This is not tail-recursive. The tail-call is to `last`, not to `recursive_factorials`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag indeed, thanks, I have removed a mention of tail recursion from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Question is about recursion, but also you can use iteration, it's faster:

```
def factorials(num)
  m = 1
  (0...num).map {|e| e.zero? ? 1 : m *= e }
end
factorials(6)
=> [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Or by using hash memoisation (I would say its a recursion too):

```
factorials = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = h[k-1] * k }.update(0 => 1)
factorials.values_at(*(0..5))
=> [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Comment: The latter is nice.

Comment: Excellent use of hash! Implicit recursion with built-in cache :-) Would upvote again if I could.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. I am so proud to listen this from such ruby master as you.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of [Ilya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43110711/477037):

```
def each_factorial
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
  m = 1
  1.step do |i|
    yield m
    m *= i
  end
end

each_factorial.take(6)
#=> [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```